# Two Unordered Lists are pushing other elements away from each other. (HTML, CSS)

Tags: html, css, web

I'm having an issue with some UL tags where if I have a second one next to the first one it pushes and squishes the footer of the web page. Does anyone have any idea why? Thank you ever so much in advance!

Code: HTML

```
<div class="container">
            <div class="paragraph-brands paragraph">
                <h1 class="brands-heading"> Brands - Find Your Favourite! </h1>

                <p class="brands-para"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing     elit. Nam malesuada vel metus sodales facilisis: </p> 

                <ul class="brands-list-1">
                    <li> BST Bathroom Accessories </li>
                    <li class="blue"> Burlington bathroom accessories </li>
                    <li> Croydex Bathroom Accessories </li>
                    <li class="blue"> Dietsche bathroom accessories </li>
                    <li> Eastbrook heated towel rails </li>
                    <li class="blue"> Elite bathroom mirrors </li>
                    <li> Euroshowers bathroom accessories </li>
                    <li class="blue"> HIB bathroom accessories </li>
                    <li> JIS heated towel rails </li>
                </ul>


                <ul class="brands-list-2">
                    <li> MHS Radiators </li>
                    <li class="blue"> Marflow bathroom accessories </li>
                    <li> Methven Deva taps </li>
                    <li class="blue"> Moods bathroom accessories</li>
                    <li> Patterson Elderly and Disabled </li>
                    <li class="blue"> Reina heated towel rails </li>
                    <li> Showerdrape bathroom accessories </li>
                    <li class="blue"> Smedbo bathroom accessories </li>
                    <li> Stuart Turner shower pumps </li>
                </ul>
            </div> <!-- Paragraph Brands -->
        </div> <!-- Container -->
    </div> <!-- Brands -->

    <footer>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="footer-list">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="index.html"> HOME </a></li>
                    <li><a href="about.html"> ABOUT </a></li>
                    <li><a href="products.html"> PRODUCTS </a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://www.bstaccessories.co.uk/"> SHOP </a></li>
                    <li><a href="contact.html"> CONTACT </a></li>
                </ul>
            </div> <!-- Footer List -->

            <div class="copyright-link">
                <p class="words"> Copyright © BSTBathrooms 2014 <br> Website: <a href="http://www.webscriptdesign.co.uk"> webscriptdesign.co.uk </p>
            </div> <!-- Copyright Link -->
        </div> <!-- Container -->
    </footer>
```

Code: CSS

```
.paragraph {
    width: 534px;
    margin-left: 36px;
    padding-top: 55px;
}

.products-heading {
    font-family: Lato;
    font-weight: 300;
    margin: 0px;
}

.products-para {
    font-family: Lato;
    font-weight: 300;
}

.list-intro {
    font-family: Lato;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 20px;
    padding-top: 10px;
}

.list-items {
    line-height: 3;
}

.list-items li {
    text-decoration: none;
    list-style: none;
    color: #07adfb;
    font-family: Lato;
    font-weight: 300;
}

.list-items li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    list-style: none;
    color: #07adfb;
    font-family: Lato;
    font-weight: 300;
}

.products-image img {
    position: relative;
    top: -380px;
    right: 36px;
    float: right;

}

/** BRANDS **/

.brands {
    height: 673px;
    width: auto;
    background-color: white;
    position: relative;
    top: -46px;
}

.brands-heading {
    font-family: Lato;
    font-weight: 300;
    margin: 0px;
}

.brands-para {
    font-family: Lato;
    font-weight: 300;
}

.brands-list-1 {
    line-height: 3;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.brands-list-1 li {
    text-decoration: none;
    list-style: none;
    font-family: Lato;
    font-weight: 300;
}

.blue {
    color: #07adfb;
}

.brands-list-2 {
    line-height: 3;
    float: right;
    height: auto;
    position: relative;
    left: 56px;
    top: -464px;
    overflow: hidden;
    clear: both;


}

.brands-list-2 li {
    text-decoration: none;
    list-style: none;
    font-family: Lato;
    font-weight: 300;
    overflow: hidden;
    clear: both;
}


/** FOOTER **/

footer {
    height: 53px;
    width: auto;
    background-color: #303030;
    position: relative;
    top: -46px;
}

.footer-list ul {
    margin: 0px;
    padding-top: 15px;
}
.footer-list ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0px;
}

.footer-list ul li a {
    margin: 0px;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: Lato;
    font-weight: 300;
    margin: 20px 20px 0px 0px;
}

.words {
    color: white;
    font-family: Lato;
    font-weight: 300;
    float: right;
    position: relative;
    top: -39px;
    right: 36px;
    line-height: 1.5;
}

.words a {
    color: white;
    font-weight: 300;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: please create a fiddle with just the relevant codes. Thank you

Comment: or use the code snippet button when you ask question..

Comment: Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kdcjj9kc/) Looks like the footer needs a `clear:both;` but that causes some other issues. So in general it is a float issue.

Comment: Thank you ever so much for that, it works! You're a star! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the two ul were causing problems in the sense that they were not sitting together properly. Upon delving deeper into your code, you have used position attributes kinda funky ( IMO anyway). So I changed a few bits and pieces...

Here is the snippet...

```css
        .paragraph {
          width: 534px;
          margin-left: 36px;
          padding-top: 55px;
        }
        .products-heading {
          font-family: Lato;
          font-weight: 300;
          margin: 0px;
        }
        .products-para {
          font-family: Lato;
          font-weight: 300;
        }
        .list-intro {
          font-family: Lato;
          font-weight: 300;
          font-size: 20px;
          padding-top: 10px;
        }
        .list-items {
          line-height: 3;
        }
        .list-items li {
          text-decoration: none;
          list-style: none;
          color: #07adfb;
          font-family: Lato;
          font-weight: 300;
        }
        .list-items li a {
          text-decoration: none;
          list-style: none;
          color: #07adfb;
          font-family: Lato;
          font-weight: 300;
        }
        .products-image img {
          position: relative;
          top: -380px;
          right: 36px;
          float: right;
        }
        /** BRANDS **/
        .brands {
          height: 673px;
          width: auto;
          background-color: white;
          position: relative;
          top: -46px;
        }
        .brands-heading {
          font-family: Lato;
          font-weight: 300;
          margin: 0px;
        }
        .brands-para {
          font-family: Lato;
          font-weight: 300;
        }
        .brands-list-1 {
          line-height: 3;
          overflow: hidden;
          /* changes here */
          width: 50%;
          float: left;
          box-sizing: border-box;
        }
        .brands-list-1 li {
          text-decoration: none;
          list-style: none;
          font-family: Lato;
          font-weight: 300;
        }
        .blue {
          color: #07adfb;
        }
        .brands-list-2 {
          /* changes here */
          line-height: 3;
          float: right;
          height: auto;
          overflow: hidden;
          width: 50%;
          box-sizing: border-box;
        }
        .brands-list-2 li {
          text-decoration: none;
          list-style: none;
          font-family: Lato;
          font-weight: 300;
          overflow: hidden;
          clear: both;
        }
        /** FOOTER **/
        footer {
          height: 53px;
          width: auto;
          background-color: #303030;
          position: relative;
          top: -46px;
          clear: both;
          /* changes here */
        }
        .footer-list ul {
          margin: 0px;
          padding-top: 15px;
        }
        .footer-list ul li {
          display: inline-block;
          margin: 0px;
        }
        .footer-list ul li a {
          margin: 0px;
          color: white;
          text-decoration: none;
          font-family: Lato;
          font-weight: 300;
          margin: 20px 20px 0px 0px;
        }
        .words {
          color: white;
          font-family: Lato;
          font-weight: 300;
          float: right;
          position: relative;
          top: -39px;
          right: 36px;
          line-height: 1.5;
        }
        .words a {
          color: white;
          font-weight: 300;
          text-decoration: none;
        }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="paragraph-brands paragraph">
    <h1 class="brands-heading"> Brands - Find Your Favourite! </h1>

    <p class="brands-para">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam malesuada vel metus sodales facilisis:</p>
    <ul class="brands-list-1">
      <li>BST Bathroom Accessories</li>
      <li class="blue">Burlington bathroom accessories</li>
      <li>Croydex Bathroom Accessories</li>
      <li class="blue">Dietsche bathroom accessories</li>
      <li>Eastbrook heated towel rails</li>
      <li class="blue">Elite bathroom mirrors</li>
      <li>Euroshowers bathroom accessories</li>
      <li class="blue">HIB bathroom accessories</li>
      <li>JIS heated towel rails</li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="brands-list-2">
      <li>MHS Radiators</li>
      <li class="blue">Marflow bathroom accessories</li>
      <li>Methven Deva taps</li>
      <li class="blue">Moods bathroom accessories</li>
      <li>Patterson Elderly and Disabled</li>
      <li class="blue">Reina heated towel rails</li>
      <li>Showerdrape bathroom accessories</li>
      <li class="blue">Smedbo bathroom accessories</li>
      <li>Stuart Turner shower pumps</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <!-- Paragraph Brands -->
</div>
<!-- Container -->
</div>
<!-- Brands -->
<footer>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="footer-list">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="index.html"> HOME </a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="about.html"> ABOUT </a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="products.html"> PRODUCTS </a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="http://www.bstaccessories.co.uk/"> SHOP </a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="contact.html"> CONTACT </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- Footer List -->
    <div class="copyright-link">
      <p class="words">Copyright © BSTBathrooms 2014
        <br>Website: <a href="http://www.webscriptdesign.co.uk"> webscriptdesign.co.uk</a> 
      </p>
    </div>
    <!-- Copyright Link -->
  </div>
  <!-- Container -->
</footer>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you ever so much for this, it works perfectly! :)

Comment: @HarryKrautschneider - glad to be of help. If you found the answer acceptable please mark it as so. Thanks